# How to prevent sensitive variable values from logging?

Tags: install4j

Using the action "Set a variable" for sensitive data like passwords or something else logs the values to the logfile. Is there a way to prevent this behavior for this kind of variables? We are using install4j version 6.0.4. I also tried to create a custom action but setting the variable with `context.setVariable(...)` has the same effect and produce a log entry like `Variable changed: my.password=abc123[class java.lang.String]`. We need to avoid this log entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
context.registerHiddenVariable("variableName")
```

for those variables.

In 6.1, for pre-defined installer variables, the configuration panel has a "Sesitive information, do not write values to the log file" check box.

Comment: Thank you. This option also exists in 6.0.4 but it do not prevent the values to be written in the `i4jparams.config` file in the `.install4j` folder inside the installation directory, am I right? So sensitive data could also be read by everybody from this file.

Comment: The solution with the `registerHiddenVariable(...)` in combination with our customized action works fine.

Comment: Okay, there is still one question left: is it possible to avoid printing the values of suppresed installer variables to the `[installtion-dir]/.install4j/i4jparams.conf`file? To avoid them from logging but be printed as clear text in some configuration file is not secure at all, is it?

Comment: The values would only be written to i4jparams.conf if they are predefined.